# Ambiguity with Task.Run

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, delegates, ambiguity

This line in main

```
Task.Run(f);
```

with this function in the same class `Program`

```
static int f() { return 0; }
```

causes this compile error (there are no other methods called `f` in `Program`):

> CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Task.Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)' and 'Task.Run(Func<Task>)'

Isn't it obviously `Func<int>` and not `Func<Task>`?

However, all of these work:

```
Task.Run(() => 0);
Task.Run(() => f());
Task.Run(async () => f());
```

Comment: I was about to say this is different from the question marked as a duplicate, as that one has an error message about `Action` and `Func<string>`, but now, I realize that this is the same in that only the return type differs in `Func<int>` and `Func<Task>`.